# Generate hash of StorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

How to generate hash (for instance md5) of file contained in StorageFile ? I'd like to store hash value in database and look into it to avoid duplicate files.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use HashAlgorithmProvider class to compute the hash

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider.aspx

Have a look at this post so you don't get OOM for large files

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e8e538b5-1d71-4ba3-b1df-b74ec8978443

Comment: thanks for answer, however you can get OutOfMemory with this approach also (if you use this function in loop - for instance adding photography files with hashes - gc won't collect it in time). I suggest to use try catch in buffer allocating (GC.Collect() + retry in catch). Also almost 100 mb buffer capacity is too much imho.